# Oracle trigger on varchar values not working

Tags: oracle, triggers, varchar

I have 2 tables 'label' and 'musician'

```
CREATE TABLE label
(labId varchar(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
labName varchar(20) NOT NULL
);



CREATE TABLE musician
(musId varchar(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 musName varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 labId varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT MusLabel FOREIGN KEY (labId) REFERENCES label(labId)
);
```

I created a trigger to limit the number of musicians a label can have within a
range of 1 to 5; so that for example a label x cannot have 6 musicians:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER before_musician_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON musician
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
total integer;
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO total
FROM musician, label
WHERE musician.labId=label.labId;
IF (total < 0 OR total > 5)
THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Invalid');
END IF;
END;
/
```

When I insert a 6th musician into the table with the same label ID, the insert statement does not 'trigger' the TRIGGER and the 6th value is added to the table.
I don't know how to fix this.
I tried a check constraint but with varchar values, it is not working either.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Your trigger makes no sense.  First of all, it is on the musicians table, but you describe the issue as labels.

Comment: Is this for a class where you have to use a trigger?  This isn't a good use for a trigger (particularly if you expect to have multiple users) and the requirement doesn't make a lot of sense-- what happens if a label wants to sign a 6th musician?  If you really want to enforce that sort of thing, you'd be better off changing the data model.

Comment: @Justin Cave yes it is an assignment for a class actually. I was wondering if I could use a check constraint in this case, and if yes how?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has multiple issues.  For instance, it is not accessing `:new`.  The trigger is on the wrong table.  It has no error generation.

I might suggest something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER before_labels_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON labels
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
  v_total integer;
  user_xcep EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT( user_xcep, -20001 );
BEGIN

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_total
    FROM labels l
    WHERE l.labId = :new.labId;
    IF (v_total >= 5) THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Invalid');
        RAISE user_xcep
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: This trigger will generate `mutating table error` because  the same table a triggering statement operates on is being queried. Yes `before insert`  row level trigger will forgive a simple `insert into .. values()` statement but `insert into select ... from` statement will fail. Plus I think if a trigger needs to be created it needs to be created on `musicians` table. Based on OP's description there is one to many relationship between labels and musicians.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I am getting the same result. It lets me insert values > 5 into the table. Maybe I need to clarify my request: what I am trying to do is limit the insert on the musicians table not the other way around, as Nicholas Krasnov correctly pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger fires BEFORE the insert, so the sixth entry doesn't exist when the query is executed.

If you want to error on the insert of the 6th entry, you can make it an AFTER trigger (and fire once per statement, rather than FOR EACH ROW).